# PHP - Insert into db MySql throught php code

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I don't know why, i can't insert a new line into my db table

I use this query:

```
 $db->write("INSERT INTO sest$myYear (esiti, esitiPositivi, esitiNegativi, ambi, nTerni, terno, sestina) VALUES ($esiti, $esitiPositivi, $esitiNegativi,$ambi,$nTerni,$terno,$sestinaString )");
```

Variables are declared before and they are int and string.
If I use the same query into a query sql, it works.
I'm using debugging and there aren't mistakes. The software executes the query and goes on.

I tried with a similar query like:

```
 $db->write("INSERT INTO sest$myYear (esiti, esitiPositivi, esitiNegativi, ambi, nTerni, terno, sestina) VALUES ('$esiti', '$esitiPositivi', '$esitiNegativi','$ambi','$nTerni','$terno','$sestinaString' )");
```

But nothing, it's the same.

I tried also another query into another table (through php) and it works. So the problem is in this query.

If you need more information, ask me.

EDIT:

This is my definition for tables and variables.

```
            $esiti = $sestinaObj[0][1];
            $esitiPositivi = $sestinaObj[1][1];
            $esitiNegativi = $sestinaObj[2][1];
            $nTerni = $sestinaObj[3][1];
            $ambi = $sestinaObj[4][1];
            $sestina = $sestinaObj[5][1];
            $colpi = $sestinaObj[6][1];
            $terno = $sestinaObj[7][1];
```

I know that I can use directly $sestinaObj into the query.

This is the method

```
function isMyComposition($ventiCinqueEstraz, $quad, $successive, $db, $myYear){


$db = new DBM();
//    if(count($ventiCinqueEstraz) <= 25) return false; 
    $sestina = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
$colpi = 0;
$count = 0;
$posizione = 0;
while($count < 2){
    for($i=0; $i<25; $i++){//NON FUNZIONA
        $sestinaObj= array(      
        array("esiti",0),
        array("esitiPositivi",0),
        array("esitiNegativi",0),
        array("nterni",0),
        array("ambi",0),
        array("sestina",array(0,0,0,0,0,0)),
        array("colpi",0),
            array("terno",0)
    );
     $sestina =   addOccurenceComp($quad, $sestina, array(     $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$i]['uno'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$i]['due'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$i]['tre'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$i]['quattro'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$i]['cinque']),$db,$myYear);
   $result =  $db->read("SELECT sestina FROM sest$myYear where sestina = $sestina ");
     for($j=25; $j<50; $j++){


  $sestinaObj = checkSestina($sestinaObj, $sestina, $quad, $colpi, $posizione, array(     $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$j]['uno'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$j]['due'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$j]['tre'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$j]['quattro'],
                                                               $ventiCinqueEstraz[$count][$j]['cinque']),$db,$myYear);
    }
      $esiti = $sestinaObj[0][1];
            $esitiPositivi = $sestinaObj[1][1];
            $esitiNegativi = $sestinaObj[2][1];
            $nTerni = $sestinaObj[3][1];
            $ambi = $sestinaObj[4][1];
            $sestina = $sestinaObj[5][1];
            $colpi = $sestinaObj[6][1];
            $terno = $sestinaObj[7][1];

    if(count($result) <= 0){
            $insertResultTerni = $db->read("SELECT Colpi from terni where colpi = $colpi");
            if($insertResultTerni[0]['Colpi'] == "")

                $db->write("INSERT INTO terni (colpi) values ($colpi)");


            $sestinaString = implode(" ",$sestina);

         $db->write("INSERT INTO sest2016 (esiti, esitiPositivi, esitiNegativi, ambi, nTerni, terno, sestina) VALUES ($esiti, $esitiPositivi, $esitiNegativi,$ambi,$nTerni,$terno,$sestinaString )");  
    }         
        else {


            $insertResultTerni = $db->write("INSERT INTO terni (colpi) values ($colpi)");
          $esiti = mysql_real_escape_string($esiti);

$db->write("INSERT INTO sest$myYear (esiti, esitiPositivi, esitiNegativi, ambi, nTerni, terno, sestina) VALUES (0,0,0,0,0,0,0)"); 
       }

      }


    $count++;
}
}
```

I know that the code is very very ugly

Edit 2:

Now I tried to change all column type into varchar and converted every variables to string. I have the same problem.

```
 $esiti = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[0][1]) ? (string)$sestinaObj[0][1] : "";
            $esitiPositivi = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[1][1]) ? (string)$sestinaObj[1][1] : "";
            $esitiNegativi = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[2][1]) ? (string)$sestinaObj[2][1] : "";
            $nTerni = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[3][1]) ? (string)$sestinaObj[3][1] : "";
            $ambi = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[4][1]) ? (string)$sestinaObj[4][1] : "";
            $sestina = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[5][1]) ? implode(" ", $sestina) : "";
            $colpi = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[6][1]) ? (string)$sestinaObj[6][1] : "" ;
            $terno = !empty((string)$sestinaObj[7][1]) ? (string)$sestinaObj[7][1] : "";

         $db->write("INSERT INTO sest2016 (esiti, esitiPositivi, esitiNegativi, ambi, nTerni, terno, sestina) "
                 . "VALUES ($esiti, $esitiPositivi, $esitiNegativi,$ambi,$nTerni,$terno,$sestina)");
```

This is the table definition
[image]

Comment: Are you checking for errors? Mysql will tell you if you have a sql error and php will tell you if you have a syntax error.

Comment: try `echo`ing the statement to screen - check for obvious mistooks and try running the query in your mysql client

Comment: Do you commit the changes anywhere?

Comment: @JohnConde Yes I checked for errors, but nothing. I don't have any error.

Comment: @RamRaider I tried echoing into the loop, but it doesn't works. So I tried at the start of the page and I have all variables = 0, but there aren't mistakes...

Comment: @BobJarvis Hi, yes i'm using git hub (I'm pretty new in php so, if the code isn't perfect, don't worry )
This is the link: https://github.com/aleShady/sitoLotto/blob/master/App/quadratureTest/sestine.php

Thank you

Comment: I didn't mean "commit code to GitHub". I meant "commit the changes made by your SQL statements to the database".

Comment: @BobJarvis Oh I'm sorry. Anyway, no i didn't made it.

I tried another query into another table and it works... So I don't know where is the mistake :(

Comment: Please edit your question (use the `edit` button, just below the tags) to include the definition of your table and the values in all the variables you're using (such as `$esiti` and `$esitiPositivi`). Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis

I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: What I think is needed is the definition of the `sest$myYear` table in the database - what all the column names are, their data types, any constraints on the table such as primary key and foreign key constraints, etc. Also, when I asked for the values of the variables I mean, what are their contents at the time that the query is executed. For example, does the variable `$esiti` contain a string or a number, and what is the value of that string or number or whatever? Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis Now I'ill try to create a table with only varchar..
Anyway, the values of the variables are Strings and Int so I think there is no problem with them...

I repeat, now I'll create a table with only varchar and variables with only String and I'll update you. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @BobJarvis I added an edit into my questione for the table definition e a new method... Thank you

Comment: You're not supplying a valid for the `Id` column. This column cannot be NULL. Is there a trigger or something similar which is setting a value in this column? Otherwise I would expect your INSERT statement to fail. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis The Id has the auto increment so I think that I don't need to insert it manually. (Sql Server works in this method)

Answer (score 1):

If a variable contains string value, and that string contains a quote, then you must escape that quote. Say you are inserting **$esiti** which is equals to **John O'Hara**, then you must escape the quote when constructing the query.

```
$esiti = mysql_real_escape_string($esiti);

$db->write("INSERT INTO sest$myYear (esiti, esitiPositivi, esitiNegativi, ambi, nTerni, terno, sestina) VALUES ('$esiti', '$esitiPositivi', '$esitiNegativi','$ambi','$nTerni','$terno','$sestinaString' )");
```

Note: mysql_real_escape_string prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but it's the same...

$esiti doesn't has quote or something like this... So maybe there is another problem, but I don't know...

Comment: I tried to insert this query:
$db->write("INSERT INTO sest$myYear (esiti, esitiPositivi, esitiNegativi, ambi, nTerni, terno, sestina) VALUES (0,0,0,0,0,0,0)"); 

But nothing, it doesn't works :(